# python socket.receive buffer

Tags: python, sockets

Working on a script to poll a smart plug and parse the json response for further use.

This works perfectly:

```
while True:
  try:
    ip = "192.168.1.130" 
    port = 9999
    sock_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock_tcp.connect((ip, port))
    cmd_emeter = commands['emeter']
    sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd_emeter))
    data_emeter = sock_tcp.recv(2048)
    sock_tcp.close()

    # decrypt, parse, and relay emeter response

    emeter = decrypt(data_emeter[4:])
    parsed_json_emeter = json.loads(emeter)
    voltage = parsed_json_emeter['emeter']['get_realtime']['voltage']
    power = parsed_json_emeter['emeter']['get_realtime']['power']
    print voltage
    print power
    publish.single("myHome/smartplug1/voltage", voltage, hostname="192.168.1.120")
    publish.single("myHome/smartplug1/power", power, hostname="192.168.1.120")



    time.sleep(5)
  except socket.error:
        quit("Cound not connect to host " + ip + ":" + str(port))
```

This does not:

```
while True:
  try:
    ip = "192.168.1.130" 
    port = 9999
    sock_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock_tcp.connect((ip, port))
    cmd_emeter = commands['emeter']
    sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd_emeter))
    data_emeter = sock_tcp.recv(2048)
    cmd_info = commands['info']
    sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd_info))
    data_info = sock_tcp.recv(2048)
    #cmd_daystats = commands['daystats']
    #sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd_daystats))
    #data_daystats = sock_tcp.recv(2048)
    sock_tcp.close()

    # decrypt, parse, and relay emeter response

    emeter = decrypt(data_emeter[4:])
    parsed_json_emeter = json.loads(emeter)
    voltage = parsed_json_emeter['emeter']['get_realtime']['voltage']
    power = parsed_json_emeter['emeter']['get_realtime']['power']
    print voltage
    print power
    publish.single("myHome/smartplug1/voltage", voltage, hostname="192.168.1.120")
    publish.single("myHome/smartplug1/power", power, hostname="192.168.1.120")

    # decrypt, parse, and relay info response

    info = decrypt(data_info[4:])
    parsed_json_info = json.loads(info)
    relay_state = parsed_json_info['system']['get_sysinfo']['relay_state']
    print relay_state
    #publish.single("myHome/smartplug1/voltage", voltage, hostname="192.168.1.120")
    #publish.single("myHome/smartplug1/power", power, hostname="192.168.1.120")

    time.sleep(5)
  except socket.error:
        quit("Cound not connect to host " + ip + ":" + str(port))
```

I need help figuring out why. Perhaps some sort of buffer issue with the sock_tcp.recv(2048) lines.

Here is the error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/share/openhab/scripts $ python HS110-relay.py
119.622975
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "HS110-relay.py", line 89, in <module>
parsed_json_info = json.loads(info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Thanks.

Baobab

Comment: What do you mean they don't work? Error, exception?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to send messages between the connections. Unless your server code handles a message protocol, a `recv` will never wait for a `send`. Have a look at [XMLRPC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.html).

Comment: Rephrased the question. Perhaps this is clearer.

Comment: Your indentation is a bit screwed up. I dont mind fixing up the code formatting, but I'd rather not edit the code itself.

Comment: Indentation should be fixed now on the post. Copy paste issue. Don't think that is causing the issue with the script.